# Can't seemed to import google cloud Vertex AI Text Sentiment Analysis Dataset

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I am experimenting with google cloud Vertex AI Text Sentiment Analysis. I created a sentiment dataset based on the following reference:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-text#sentiment-analysis

When I created the dataset, I specified that maximum sentiment is 1 to get a range of 0-1. The document indicate that CSV file should have the following format:

[ml_use],gcs_file_uri|"inline_text",sentiment,sentimentMax

So I created a csv file with something like this:

My computer is not working.,0,1
You are really stupid.,1,1

As indicated in the documentation, I need at least 10 entry per sentiment value. I created 11 entries for the value 0 and 1, resulting in 22 entries total. I then uploaded the file and got "Unable to import data due to error", but the error message is blank. There doesn't appear to be errors logged in the log explorer.

I tried importing a text classification model and it imported properly. The imported line looks something like this.

The flowers are very pretty,happy
The grass are dead,sad

What am I doing wrong here for the sentiment data?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue appears to be character set related. I had generate the CSV file using Libre Office Calc and exported it as CSV. Out of the box, it appears to default to a western europe character set, which looked fine in my text editor, but apparently caused problems I changed it to UTF-8 and now it's importing my dataset.